# How to distribute public keys in the network without losing its credibility?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

How to solve the key distribution encrypted with the public key?
How to make public key authentication? How to distribute public keys in the network without losing its credibility?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Can you clarify what you want to do and what you mean by "losing credibility"?

Comment: The key distribution in encryption Solved with the public key, Do you know How?And How can trust the public key?

Comment: You always need some kind of trust root. Perhaps a certificate-authority, perhaps a web-of-trust, or a fingerprint verified through a different channel. But which of these is appropriate is application and use dependent, and you didn't say anything about that.

Comment: In fact I mean If the data are encrypted by the public key,
Since the only holder of the private key can decrypt it,
so that,confidentiality is maintained.
But the problem is that anyone can have access to the public key,so authentication is difficult.
What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: The sender needs his own key-pair and then signs the message with his private key. (Search for digital signature)

Answer (score 4):

Distributing a public key does not affect its security. That's why it's called a **public** key. If you, on the other hand, distribute the **private** key, then in that case you will be giving everyone who has access to that private key the authority to act as if they own the key pair.